# External 3.5'' hdd connected to desktop. Can the external hdd get damaged if the desktop power is suddenly off?

Tags: external-hard-drive, power-supply

To explain better the question:
If the power supply of a external hdd remains on, while the desktop is suddenly shutdown (not safely, but by lack of power) can the external hdd be damaged/bad sectors/reduce life expectancy even tough that the external hdd power remais on?

Thanks for any hint on this.

Comment: Yes, because the drive was suddenly disconnected from the system it was connected to so data could be corrupted lost.

Comment: If in the middle of a write, then yes (data corrupted) . Otherwise if the external HDD drive remains on, it should be fine. That said I have not seen a PC go off (lack of power) and the attached HDD stay on.